# Python "For" loop output discrepancy

Tags: python, csv

I am running a forloop and it is running fine but it keeps bringing up the last row in the file even though it has errors: The print out looks like this: The last line is supposed to look like the rest.

```
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again
['Delete', 'Service Group', 'CR-Web-ISD']
all error checks done!
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
#!usr/bin/python


from subprocess import *
import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, solution_id, input_file = argv

#creating time stamp and returning as a string to add to solution id log name
def timeIzNow():  
    full = time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return full

#set up logging to file[
LOG_FILENAME = solution_id  + timeIzNow() 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s %(process)d',
                    datefmt='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 
                    filename=LOG_FILENAME,
              filemode='w')   
# defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# setting a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# telling the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# adding the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

#set up configuration Parser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/objectItems.cfg')
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/action.cfg')

#set up configuration Parser to get objects and check the csv file for matches
objects = config.get('Objects', 'objects')

#get actions
actions = config.get('Actions', 'actions')

#if no object is found, run error
assert(sys.argv[1] != None), "object does not exist"

#logging debug 
#logging.debug('object does not exist')

#Get inputs and check value and path to file
try:
    f = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb")) 
except:
    logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')   
else:
    try:
        for line in f:
            for column in f:          
                if solution_id != column[2]:
                    print "Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again"
    except ValueError: 
                logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
    else:
        print column    

finally: 
     print "all error checks done!"
```

Comment: Please show us the command-line arguments you passed to the script.

Comment: why this double for-loop? In the last block, there is never a ValueError raised, so the else-Block is executed.

Comment: your try/except  block looks a bit dodgy, also what is the `else:print column` supposed to be doing?

Comment: is that first `for line in f:` just to throw away he first line of the csv file? Won't the inner for loop exhaust the iterator? Or will it start again ... gotta go play

Comment: Yep, just tested it in ipython. The outer for only executes once (reads the first line of the file) then the inner loop drains `f`

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code (you really just needed to quote this part):

```
try:
    for line in f:
        for column in f:          
            if solution_id != column[2]:
                print "Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again"
except ValueError: 
            logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
else:
    print column
```

This says

- (`try`) Try running the following loop.
- (`except ValueError`) If at any time you encounter a ValueError, log the error and continue after the loop.  (If you encounter any other kind of Exception it will be thrown and the program will execute the `finally` block and terminate).
- (`else`) if you finish the entire loop and have not encountered an exception, the print the current contents of the variable `column`.

Since the loop is completing without an exception being raised, the `else` clause is executed.  Since the loop has run to completion, the current value of `column` is that read from the last line of the file.

You didn't show us the input file, but I'll wager that you're getting the `print column` statement executed *in addition to* regular output for the last line, not *instead of* that output.

Comment: Shouldn't the inner for be `for column in line`?

Comment: Quite possibly.  I'm not trying to figure out what the user intended to do, rather I'm trying to answer the OP's question about what the `print column` line is executed.

Comment: Yep, but that might be why his "python for loop [is] not working as it should"

Comment: The part I took to the question in the original post is *"it keeps bringing up the last row in the file even though it has errors: The print out looks like this: The last line is supposed to look like the rest."*  I definitely don't want to suggest that the rest of the code is correct, however.

Comment: Yes, and your answer is correct on that .. just inquiring minds, you know?

Comment: As for the rest of the code, BTW, I think it *might* be the case that the user is treating the CSV file as a list literal and not `eval`ing it.  Or something.  Without the input file it's hard to guess.